# How to perform a Offset Compensation Procedure for a BLE Cycling Power Meter

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an iOS application written in Swift that is able to communicate with a variety of BLE cycling based devices: heart rate monitor, speed and cadence sensor, trainers and of course power meters.

My question is regarding how to perform a Offset Compensation Procedure as described in the [Cycling Power Profile document](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=412769).

I have the following code to perform this operation:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    ...
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! as [CBCharacteristic] {
        switch characteristic.uuid.uuidString {
        case POWER_CONTROL:
            var rawArray:[UInt8] = [0x0C];
            let data = NSData(bytes: &rawArray, length: rawArray.count)
            peripheral.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristic, type:   CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            print("POWER CONTROL")

...
```

What ends up happening is, well, nothing except that the power meter disconnects itself every thirty seconds or so. If I don't issue this command it does not disconnect itself. Thus this command is definitely causing the disconnect.

What is the proper procedure to performing this operation ? Am I to disconnect from the device, reconnect, issue the calibration command when I find a power meter and then disconnect and reconnect again ?

I am confused when this operation can happen and how I will be notified when it's worked or failed.

Comment: I don't want to even try and understand iOS BLE, but i assume that POWER_CONTROL is the control point and that you have enabled it for indications. If so, what does the indication on the control point say? Also, does the power meter feature indicate support for this feature. Myself I am trying to figure out what 'offset compensation' means and what it does and why I, as a client, would want to do this.

Comment: I'll ask another question. It looks like you are trying to initiate a client write on the POWER_CONTROL characteristic from a callback. If writeValue returns immediately I suppose that's okay. Otherwise you maybe blocking the receive callback.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Writing [0x0c] in a single-byte write is correct.  Make sure to turn on notifications on the characteristic first so you receive the response.  I have found that on some devices it makes sense to slip in some 50-100ms delays between each BLE op.  @BrianReinhold a zero-offset procedure tells a powermeter that there's no load on it, so it can store the zero-load reading.  It's like tareing a bathroom scale.